# CMake configure script can't find include file

Tags: cmake, gdal, proj

I am trying to update some git submodules (`proj.4` and `gdal`) to newer versions (6.1.0 and 3.0.0, respectively) but I am running into some errors when trying to `make gdal` through `cmake`. The error occurs when it runs `gdal`'s configure script. The error has to do with not being able to find `proj.h`, a header file from the `proj.4` project.

```
checking for PROJ >= 6 library...
checking for proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for internal_proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... no
checking for internal_proj_create_from_wkt in -lproj... yes
configure: `error: proj.h not found`
```

Right now I am manually running the gdal configure command in the gdal directory:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS=-I/proj.h/dir --with-proj=/proj/install/dir --prefix=/gdal/install/dir
```

In the `config.log` that results after it errors, the `g++` command that it fails on has a `-I` that matches the one provided in the configure command. I verified that the `-I` path has the "proj.h" header file that it says it can't find.

I expect it to pass with this so I'm not sure what else it would need to find the file.

Comment: That looks like you are running an autotools generated configure script.  Are you sure you gave it the correct paths because they look incorrect to me.

Comment: "... trying to `make gdal` through `cmake`" - Running `./configure` is part of autotools, it is not a CMake approach. I see no relation of the `cmake` tag with a question post.

Comment: `CXXFLAGS="-I/proj.h/dir -L<path to libproj.so>"`